# Dealing with prices and rounding in Javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, decimal

So, as we all know, `0.1 + 0.2` is equivalent to `0.30000000000000004`.

I've got an application which will be used at a point of sell to collect money, and I don't want to deal with the nightmare of floating point arithmetic. My options, as I see them, are

**a)** using integers and dealing with prices as Cents/Pence, doing the math there, and then dividing by 100 to get the cost in Dollars/Pounds

**b)** using a Decimal library to do accurate math on the numbers

I'm using react.js and webpack. Anybody with production experience have any advice? I'm leaning toward option a.

Comment: Yes. Store all prices as cent amounts. (btw, I did write an accounting app and simply used `toFixed(2)` on floats loaded from a DB; no issues so far)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an established convention to do all currency operations (and any operation that has a fixed number of decimal places for that matter) as integer operations and convert that value to decimal for display. Use a decimal library only if accuracy is vital and the number of decimal places varies from number to number.

Comment: "*It is an established convention to do all currency operations as integer operations*" is it? I've certainly seen that used but I wouldn't call that a *convention* - it's just something cheap you can do to avoid floating point arithmetic as a whole, not necessarily bound to currencies. I thought the commonly accepted variant was to use a dedicated type for money. That is, if you want to be dealing a lot with them - if you just need rather light calculations (e.g., calculating the total of selected items), then you're fine with integers.

Comment: `dedicated type for money` -> What would that do differently? If I ever use multiple currencies I use a class that contains the value as an integer, the currency code, and the conversion factor to get back to dollars/pounds/euros etc for currencies that aren't 100 pennies in to a unit.

Comment: I'd use a library for money and let it handle this. If I have to implement my own, I'd avoid using primitive types to represent the money and choose something like BigDecimal to hold the data. Because you hit tons of problems as soon as you have non-trivial operations with money. Like exchange rates - `moneyAmount * exchangeRate` is bound to give you the wrong result sooner or later. And if you do a double conversion (from currency A -> to base -> to currency B) you get two opportunities for wrong conversion. I've seen this. You can also get a quadruple jump if you do A->B->A or A->B->C

Comment: You can start multiplying numbers to avoid any form of floating point arithmetic but then you start losing precision with large values - removing decimals and allowing more significant digits for exchange rates, might run you a total of 8 orders of magnitude reduction of `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. Which really starts to limit you. You can still fit ~900mil there but that might not be enough, depending on your needs. We've not even talked about formatting for display yet - `toLocaleString()` works but you'll find you want something more sophisticated when you have more cultures and users.

Comment: At the very least, you want to know what the currency of this number is. If you have different items, you might have to show `100 USD`, next to `200 CAD`, next to `300 CNY`, and `400 EUR`. If you only hold the amount, you have to figure a way to find what currency `500` is in. But having the currencies would also allow you to sum more effectively, even if you just disallow `100 USD + 200 CAD` because the currency is different. If you allow it, you start converting going back to the first point. So you see why "just multiply and use integers" is a bad standard. Again, unless for trivial stuff.

Comment: I don't really have much need for exchange rate conversions but I can see why your implementation would be better for that. I tend to just stick with a base currency for all calculations and then convert everything at the end for display in the other currency. We tend to handle all transactions in one currency anyway and let third parties handle the conversion.

Comment: I worked for a company that dealt with financial data with clients from all over the world. So we had to support multiple currencies. Moreover, it was completely valid for each *user* to see values in different currencies because they might work in, say, EUR themselves but were paid in CNY from one party, and GBP from another. The system itself had its own base currency to manage everything, so which might be USD. However, we didn't do any money calculations in JS because of the lack of precision - it was handled in Java on the server then passed back. Still with a dedicated type.

Comment: Even then, we had a dedicated money type on the frontend to represent amounts. It was a rather simple container `{value: number, currency: string}` with very little logic thrown in but overall it was still useful. When displaying money the container did it automatically. Also, if putting a `Money` type in a field, then we could check for that and right-align the text. Say, in a table where normally all cells are left-aligned but `1234` and `567` are hard to compare at a glance.

Comment: @James: "dedicated type for money -> What would that do differently?" Lots of things, i.e. deal with percentages, currency conversions, annuities, etc, which do not always **result** in numbers with 2-4 decimals. It would also make handling a fixed point conversion (i.e. scaling the integer) transparent. And no, it is **not** a convention to use integers. Many use a Decimal or BigDecimal type for this or even a dedicated currency or money type.